# cinema App in Iphone

Tags: iphone

M very new to this field of iphone development.I need to make one app in which customer will be Purchasing ticket for movie by selecting the Location,Movie,Timing of show and seat.

Can anyone help me out in implementing Ticket Purchasing Part.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that people can help. Just try to ask a question.

Comment: What exactly problem you have with it? You must be more specific in your questions

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't asked a specific question and you say nothing about your experience in other programming languages I can give you some hints:

1. Look at the WWDC videos on http://developer.apple.com
2. Understand the Model-View-Controller paradigm
3. Make sure you really understood the  Model-View-Controller paradigm
4. Start with designing your user interface first. Take your time for this. Make mockups on paper, each sheet of paper corresponds to a screen and play with it and show it to some colleagues and watch if they get what to do on each screen. You can also do this in Photoshop or Illustrator or omnigraffle, but in the early stage maybe paper is a simple option.
5. Build a mockup of your app on the phone itself. Using UIImageViews you can insert the digital screens made digitally to the phone and see how it looks like. Show this version to you customers. If they like the design and feature, you can go on coding.
6. Code everything

If you want to write a serious application it is good to invest a lot into design. The coding itself is much easier if you know how it will look like in the end, because then you can design the underlying model such that it will be great for your UI.